# TcpClient SocketException with timeout after 20s no matter what

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient, networkstream

I'd like to wait for a slow response from a client with `TcpClient` but get a timeout after about 20s no matter how I configure it. This is my attempt:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient { ReceiveTimeout = 9999999, SendTimeout = 9999999 })
{
    await client.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        // Some quick read/writes happen here via the stream with stream.Write() and stream.Read(), successfully.

        // Now the remote host is calculating something long and will reply if finished. This throws the below exception however instead of waiting for >20s.
        var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(new byte[8], 0, 8);
    }
}
```

The exception is an `IOException`:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond.

...which contains a `SocketException` inside:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

`SocketErrorCode` is `TimedOut`.

The 20s [seems to be an OS default on Windows](https://serverfault.com/a/671453/203275) but isn't it possible to override it from managed code by interacting with `TcpClient`? Or how can I wait for the response otherwise?

I've also tried the old-style `BeginRead`-`EndRead` way and the same happens on `EndRead`. The problem is also not caused by Windows Firewall or Defender.

Comment: Update: if I try to run ReadAsync() again after it fails one time I'll get "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". It' my suspicion that the remote host causes this whole issue but even before this I couldn't find any sign that it would close the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the remote host wasn't responding in a timely manner, hence the problem. Let me elaborate, and though this will be a solution very specific to my case maybe it will be useful for others too.

The real issue wasn't a timeout per se, as the exception indicated, but rather what exceptions thrown on subsequent `Read()` calls have shown: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

The remote host wasn't purposely closing the connection. Rather what happened is that when it was slow to respond it was actually so busy that it wasn't processing any TCP traffic either. While the local host wasn't explicitly sending anything while waiting for a response this still was an issue: the local host tried to send ACKs for previous transmissions of the remote host. Since these couldn't be delivered the local host determined that the remote host "forcibly closed" the connection.

I got the clue from looking at the traffic with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (always good to try to look at what's beneath the surface instead of guessing around): it was apparent that while the remote host was busy it showed complete radio silence. At the same time Wireshark showed retransmission attempts carried out by the local host, indicating that this is behind the issue.

Thus the solution couldn't be implemented on the local host either, the behavior of the remote host needed to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to wait for a slow response from a client

It's important to note that it's the *connection* that is failing. The connection timeout is only for establishing a connection, which should always be very fast. In fact, the OS will accept connections *on behalf of* an application, so you're literally just talking about a packet round-trip. 21 seconds should be plenty.

Once the connection is established, then you can just remove the `ReceiveTimeout`/`SendTimeout` and use asynchronous reads to wait forever.

Comment: Funny enough, I've just read your blogpost: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html :-) ('m trying to use TCP keep-alive or a custom "keep-alive" protocol). The problem is that it's the async read that fails. Connecting succeeds and while I stripped that code off for brevity there is also some write/read happening successfully between the connection and the above slow ReadAsync(). So everything works fine until the remote host would take >20s to send data again.

Comment: @Piedone: I hate to say this, but are you *absolutely sure* that's what you're seeing? I ask because there *is* no timeout on asynchronous socket reads (for the .NET socket objects). `ReceiveTimeout` is ignored for asynchronous reads. If the server never sends anything, then the client should just sit there waiting forever.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what happens from what I see. After some successful stream.Write() and stream.Read() calls if ReadAsync() gets data from the remote quickly, then it works; if not, timeout (the whole code works properly if that response is faster like around 1s). Also supposedly the connection is open at the time the timeout happens: FWIW TcpClient.Connected == true. Also I just noticed that I didn't include the GetStream() call in the sample, clarified it.

Comment: And BTW the same happens with a Read() as waiting in a loop.

Comment: @Piedone: Sounds like you should reduce the code to the minimum code that reproduces the issue.